# How to prevent javafx from causing illegalargumentexception in image?

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to display a picture in a box with JavaFX. I followed methods documented on Oracle, but it still did not work, though it was extremely similar to the example shown on Oracle. My code is here:

```
public class TesterJavaFX extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image img = new Image("character.png");
    ImageView imgview = new ImageView();
    imgview.setImage(img);
    imgview.setFitWidth(100);
    imgview.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imgview.setSmooth(true);
    imgview.setCache(true);
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().add(imgview);
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(box);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I have a file called rocket.png in the "src" directory. It even shows up on the IDE. But Java causes a illegal argument exception, and i don't know why. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Note: The imports are all present.

Comment: Which line gives you the illegal argument exception, and what is the message associated with the exception?

Comment: is your image located in src/main/resources ? Check your img for null after loading.

Comment: The line that gives me the error is the Image declaration. Also, what is that directory? I do not have that.

Comment: Is your class in a package? If so, is the image in the same location as the class relative to the classpath, or is it in the classpath root?

Answer (score 1):

The string passed to the `Image` constructor is a URL. If the image file is in the root of your classpath, the following should work:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("/character.png").toExternalForm());
```